# Windows Phone 8.1: Save list in app settings/storage

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I just started developing a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

The app allows the user to add 'data' (strings) to his favorites-list.
Now the question is:

What is the best way to save the list or the single entries of the list so I am able load these favorites again on the next app start?

I thought I should save the data to a (text-) file so I can read it line by line and put the list together again.

What do you think, is this the best way to handle something like this? I am new to the Windows Phone 8.1 platform and any help is really appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think i finally got it to work. Should thought about something like that much earlier.

So I got my *async Task SaveAppSettingsAsync()* and just call it in the Suspending-Event and in my Hardwarebuttons_Pressed-Event when the app closes:

```
private async void OnSuspending(object sender, SuspendingEventArgs e)
    {
        var deferral = e.SuspendingOperation.GetDeferral();


        await SaveAppSettingsAsync();


        deferral.Complete();
    }

private async void HardwareButtons_BackPressed(object sender, BackPressedEventArgs e)
    {
        Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        if (rootFrame != null)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            if (rootFrame.CurrentSourcePageType == typeof(MainPage))
            {
                await SaveAppSettingsAsync();

                this.Exit();
            }
            else if (rootFrame.CanGoBack)
                rootFrame.GoBack();
        }
    }
```

Thanks for helping. I think I got better at understanding how to handle async tasks now. As I said - I'm new to Windows Phone and never really used them before.

Answer (score 2):

The best method depends on size of data and your needs. As for saving it in Settings you can try to make an array of string upon save and make list upon loading data. Simple example can look like this:

```cs
List<string> favourites = new List<string>();
protected void Method()
{
    // save as array
    ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myList"] = favourites.ToArray();

    // retrive your array and make a list from it
    favourites = ((string[])ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["myList"]).ToList();
}
```

Remember that *LocalSettings* support only simple types and have other limits - for more information [take a look at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464917.aspx#app_settings).

Comment: The strings I need to save are about 70 characters - some less, some more. There should be no limitation of adding more and more favorites over time. I didn't really find an answer: How big can the List/Array be if I save it in the local settings?

Comment: @Reality80 It should surely handle string 70 characters long, but I'm not sure if it's a good idea to use it for 'infinite' number of favourites. I've not tested settings with large number of data, in this case I think storagefile will be better (safer). I also don't know about size limit, in docs you will find limits for RoamingSettings but they don't stand for LocalSettings.

Comment: @Romsaz Thank you so far. I already tested this method in my app, it works. But I also think that this isn't the 'correct' way for a favorites-list without a number of limiation. A limiation would not make much sense in my application.
I already implemented the code for writing and reading the favorites of a text file in the local app folder. But I have on problem with it:
How can I create/write on the file when suspending the app? All the methods are async and the app closes before it writes to the text file. How can I accomplish this task to make it work?

Comment: @Reality80 You have *App.Suspending* event - you can put the code there and you can also make it *async* - in this case remember to [obtain a deferral](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.applicationmodel.suspendingoperation.getdeferral) - some info you may find also [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13421659/2681948).

Comment: I still dont know if I got it right. If I debug my app the _async save method_ (**before** _deferral.Complete()_) works as excepted when I choose the suspend lifecycle in the debugger toolbar. But how can I test it it in 'real time' on the smartphone? Even if I deploy the release the suspend event does not fire?

Comment: @Reality80 In 'real time' suspended event is callet within few seconds after your app goes to background (start button, launcher, something). To check it - maybe provide an indicator for test - create a file, change a property or other.

Comment: Is the suspend event firing if I close the app with _this.close()_ method? Maybe thats my mistake because I implemented the _HardwareButtons_BackPressed_ event and modified it that my app closes completely (this.close) if the users presses the back button on the main page.

Comment: @Reality80 I'm not sure, but it may not be fired, the same as if you hold back button and click the 'x' in upper right corner. You may try to use Window.Current.Activated event.

Comment: Window.Current.Activated? Why activated? I want to save the favorites to the txt file when the app closes completely. I don't understand what you mean - sorry.

Comment: @Reality80 And when does it close completely? Only in two cases (without suspending): once you call terminate/close/exit method - before it you can save your favourite. Nah, I see you have alraedy the answer ;)